# I have BeautifulSoup4, from Anaconda, but I can't seem to utilize it, to save URL to TXT

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this view in Anaconda.

[image]

However, I can't see to utilize BS in my script.

```
import string
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

#import BeautifulSoup as bs

alphabets = string.ascii_lowercase
for i in alphabets:
    #print(i)
    html = urlopen("http://www.airlineupdate.com/content_public/codes/airportcodes/airports-by-iata/iata-" + i + ".htm")
    print(html)

    for j  in html:
        #soup = bs4(html, "html.parser")
        soup = bs(html, "html.parser")
        f = open('C:\\Users\\Excel\\Desktop\\URL.txt', 'w')
```

When I try to run the code above, I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BeautifulSoup4'
```

Can someone enlighten me as to what's going on here?

Answer (score 4):

from [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) its

`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

and based on your code, it seems like you want to use it as `bs()`

`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs`

Comment: I tried that.  Now I get this - NameError: name 'bs4' is not defined.  Does anyone have any idea what that means?  I'm thinking that the URL doesn't allow scraping, I don't think this is a coding error.

Comment: @ryguy72 - This is definitely a coding error. After fixing the import as above, you need to then use `soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")` instead of `soup = bs(html, "html.parser")`.

Comment: @ryguy72 you can do what Nathan said, or use `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs`

Comment: @Nathan, when I run the script I get a message that says: HTTPError: Forbidden
I Made a few small changes to my original script, based on the comments and feedback that I received, and updated my original post.  Either there is still something wrong with my code, or the site is blocking my scraping actions.  All I really want to do is loop through A-Z characters and download some data from the web.  I am just doing this as a learning exercise.  If there is a better site for what I want to do, I would love to hear about it.  Thanks!